# NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete: deleting UITableView row but not object

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am successfully deleting rows in UITableView only to find out that the object itself is not deleted. This is causing bugs as predicateWithFormat: does not return the right number of records since deleted objects are counted to.

Please find below my deletion code. What should be added or changed?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
        [[_fetcher.fetchedObjects[indexPath.row] MR_inContext:localContext] MR_deleteInContext:localContext];
    }];
}
```

}
    - (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id )sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {
    if (_userMovingTableRows) return;

```
switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        break;
}
```

}

Comment: Show where you delete the object and save.

Comment: @Mundi: I've updated my code with few more lines.

Comment: @Mundi: Resolved. Found a way to have my overall code working without actually deleting the object. But I would still take your answer if it happens to add value.

Comment: From your comment it is not clear what the actual issue is. Never mind.

Comment: @Mundi: Yes, it was VERY hard to explain. Harder to explain than to fix. But thanks for your willingness to help :-)